# Simplify and remove duplicates in a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have a path as seen in this screenshot:

[image: Compound path]

After "release compound path", I have multiple path segments superimposed on each other:

[image: Released path]

Ho can I make one path from several paths?

Answer (score 1):

Select the paths and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, this will join the anchor points and give you one path.

If you have duplicates on top of each other you can select all of them then <kbd>shift</kbd> click the top one to deselect it and press <kbd>delete</kbd> to remove the underlying ones. Then use the above to connect the paths together.